# How to resolve Bad Request - Header Field Too Long while redirecting the user to loginRedirect in Msal.js

Tags: cookies, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

From our web application we are authenticating user [Azure AD B2C] through [Msal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) and version is 1.2.1. Facing an issue while redirecting user to loginRedirect() when acquireTokenSilent throwing "User Login Required".

Issue is "Bad Request - Header Field Too Long" and Http Status is 400, browser [Chrome -Ver - 80.0.3987] cookies had chunk of entries like below -

[image: chunk-of-cookies]

Forcing user to logout() and redirecting to loginRedirect() did not resolve the issue. Still cookies are available, probably cookies are not cleaning due to this -
[msal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/ea6a415f678017237cc6d2f0ba493076950bdf8f/lib/msal-core/src/UserAgentApplication.ts#L928)
[image: msal-js]

I want to clear cookies by using "[clearMsalCookie](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/9d809a9fe7618768bc35614c7a457110fd8c96a9/lib/msal-core/src/cache/AuthCache.ts#L211)" method, but it requires "State". Where do I get the State? or else is there a way to delete the msal cookies. However "resetCacheItems" not clearing the cookies....

Regards,
Deb

--

Comment: Are you using `login.microsoftonline.com` or `*.b2clogin.com`?

Comment: @Jenny - `*.b2clogin.com`

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. The user has to clear the cookies frequently which is not a good way. Even after calling `logout()` I get the same issue very often.

Comment: yes, clear the cookies solved the problem, or you can use incognito mode to login to overcome this.   but the cause of the problem is still unknown, and it will happen again next time.